# Instantiate TypeScript variable based type definition with null

Tags: typescript

I have the following type definition (generated by a framework):

```
export type SecretCategory = { 'Password' : null } |
{ 'Note' : null } |
{ 'Document' : null };
```

How can I create a variable of type `SecretCategory`?

Comment: Pick (at least) one of the union members, define a property with the relevant name and assign the value null: https://tsplay.dev/mL3Y4N.

Comment: The comment of @jonrsharpe is the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in your typescript file first import SecretCategory from the file it's defined in:

```
import { SecretCategory } from "file-Adress";
```

then you can use it like this:

```
var secretCategory: SecretCategory;
```

Comment: Thanks, but SecretCategory is supposed to be a representation of an enumeration with the values "Password", "Note" and "Document". I assume that I should be able to set somehow one of these values when creating the variable, isn't it?

Comment: The comment to my question of @jonrsharpe is the solution, thanks!